# How to generate API running when Stackdriver alert me?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am following this doc.
I know Cloud functions make an HTTP request to your function, run the following command.
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/

I'd like to run a API that created in advance when the Stackdriver alerts may be triggered. I have already defined simple custom log-based metrics in GCP.

For example, I create a Stackdriver Alert detecting an unexpected error GAE log.
I want system to be down if that alert me.

It is possible to autmatic control APIs using StackDriver Alerting and Cloud funtions?　 if you were me?